# Django: django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError

Tags: django, django-runserver

I was making new project and app.

Then when I have typed 'python3 manage.py runserver'

```
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0013_auto_20210902_0542 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')
```

This error come to me.

And even if I delete 'all' of my app's migrations forder It's still hapening

This error is hapening to all of my projects and apps

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader

Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 453, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "/home/kimhaju/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0013_auto_20210902_0542 dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0012_alter_user_first_name_max_length')
```

Comment: At some point did you modify the code in `site-packages/django` and then run `makemigrations`? Try uninstalling and re-installing Django to get a fresh install

Comment: I have tried uninstall and installing django. But same error.

(My django version is 2.2)

Comment: Can you find where the migration `auth.0013_auto_20210902_0542` comes from? It's not from the installed version of Django, you must have either created it or have a different `auth` app installed?

Comment: I can't find where is the 'auth.0013_auto_20210902_0542' is!

Comment: did you find any solution, I'm facing same error

Comment: inside "migrations" folder change 0001_initial.py -> dependencies to `migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),`